# Design implementation

Tags: java, algorithm

I am implementing a network application that has an associated set of "types". Namely:

```
    /** Universal type **/
    INTEGER(0x0002),
    BIT_STRING(0x0003),
    OCTET_STRING(0x0004),
    NULL(0x0005),
    OBJECT_ID(0x0006),
    SEQUENCE(0x0010),
    /** Application specific **/
    IP_ADDRESS(0x0040),
    COUNTER32(0x0041),
    GAUGE32(0x0042),
    TIME_TICKS(0x0043),
    OPAQUE(0x0044),
    COUNTER64(0x0046),
    UNSIGNED_INTEGER(0x0047);
```

---

In my application I have to assign constraints on various types, as well as encode/decode them from a given type. Is there any way around not having to create a separate class for each one?

Eg: `Unsigned Integer` + `Gauge32` + `Counter32` are all of the type `long`. They just have different constraints. Integer can be `+- LONG.MAX` , Gauge can only be `positive long values`, and counter can only be `positive long values` as well.

Is there a design pattern that can account for these type of details?

Comment: Makes sense to have separate classes for them. Maybe write a small code generator to do the job for you? That way you can re-create the classes automatically during a build whenever the specification changed

Comment: Do you think it would be feasible to use something like http://www.antlr.org/ for this task?

Comment: I don't think you need something as sophisticated as code generation for this pretty simple design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use inheritance. For example:

```
abstract class BaseLong {
    protected long value;

    public void setValue(final long value) throws YourControlException {
        if (checkValue(value)) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    protected abstract void checkValue(final long value) throws YourControlException;
}

class UnsignedInteger extends BaseLong {
     @Override
    protected void checkValue(final long value) throws YourControlException {
        // Check if the value is ok for UnsignedInteger and throw as appropriate
    }
}

class Gauge32 extends BaseLong {
    @Override
    protected void checkValue(final long value) throws YourControlException {
        // Check if the value is ok for Gauge32 and throw as appropriate
    }
}
```

Note that you can use an already existing `Exception` (e.g. `UnsupportedOperationException`) instead of `YourControlException`. Also you can have methods return true/false instead of throwing an exception, but I personally prefer the exceptions way.

Also note that there's no unsigned values in Java, so `UnsignedInteger` has to be 32-bits max.

---

After defining the classes, I also suggest you create some kind of factory to create these objects, in which case it would be also nice to have a base class for all your types, like `Type`, so you have your factory return only that kind of object.

Comment: This was my original idea, I guess I'll just stick to this for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure of whether the code you are posting in itself reflects a correct design.

However to answer your question, yet it is possible with Java 8:

I suspect you have an enum, even though you do not explicitely show it:

```
public enum Type {
    /** Universal type **/
    INTEGER(0x0002, l -> true),
    BIT_STRING(0x0003, l -> true),
    OCTET_STRING(0x0004, l -> true),
    NULL(0x0005, l -> true),
    OBJECT_ID(0x0006, l -> true),
    SEQUENCE(0x0010, l -> true),
    /** Application specific **/
    IP_ADDRESS(0x0040, l -> true),
    COUNTER32(0x0041, l -> true),
    GAUGE32(0x0042, l -> true),
    TIME_TICKS(0x0043, l -> true),
    OPAQUE(0x0044, l -> true),
    COUNTER64(0x0046, l -> true),
    UNSIGNED_INTEGER(0x0047, l -> true);

    private final int code;
    private final LongPredicate predicate;

    private Type(final int code, final LongPredicate predicate) {
        this.code = code;
        this.predicate = predicate;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public boolean test(final long input) {
        return predicate.test(input);
    }
}
```

Here you can specify a specific predicate for a constraint, for example for positive longs you have:

```
l -> (l > 0);
```

Which maps `l` to `l > 0`. These `LongPredicate`s could then also be made `private static` such that you can reference one concrete instance.

You can check the `long input` once you have determined that it is of a certain `Type`, by calling `Type.test(input);`.

Comment: Lol, nice one. I think this is just a some custom file format, it's nice to see how it basically "happens" to be Java as well

Comment: It actually is Java, I just omitted the enum as I didn't think it was really relevant to what I was asking for.

Comment: @Swiki thanks for the suggestion but I think I'm going to stick with Java 7 for now. Also it's not my design implementation, I'm going off a specification - namely `SNMP`.

Comment: @DiljotR This code is still possible to be refactored to Java 7 by creating your own `LongPredicate` interface and then using anonymous classes to mimic the lambda expressions, as you will be using only a few concrete predicate implementations. Just for your info as I am aware that not everyone wants to start using Java 8 just yet.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info Skiwi, this project is pretty large and I'm sure I can use your recommendation somewhere else.